# What is the purpose of the CCD id element when we use UUID for the root value?

Tags: xml, standards, hl7

I know it is used for identification, but when I see UUID's being used for various sections inside the CCD/CDA, I wonder if it is only for identification inside the document, i.e not in the database of the sender or receiver for identifying the particular record.

```
<id root="5edd43a9-0e70-4b32-9bce-7950c5cfcbee"/>
```

Would "5edd43a9-0e70-4b32-9bce-7950c5cfcbee" be stored in any database to tie it to that record, or is it only generated randomly when generating the CCD, and only ever used when looking at archived versions of transmitted CCD's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just been working on a few projects involving CCD & CCR documents (Mainly CCR).

Looking at http://www.onehealthport.com/HIE/Companion_Guide%20_CCD_Version1dot1.pdf it seems that the id is for the benefit of the document creator. What the creator uses the ID for would be up to them (logging, reviewing past documents, flagging particular documents as having errors, whatever).

We don't store the generated number anywhere, but I don't see why someone wouldn't/couldn't for their own benefit.

Not sure if this answers your question, but I hope if helps.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps. That PDF you linked seems like a slightly customized version of CCD, they use tags like `problemAct` which don't exist in CDA. HL7 documentation is terrible, it simply leaves too many questions unanswered, and I will probably mark this as an answer if nobody else can give me a definitive answer.

Comment: @user453441 - yeah I know what you mean. Documentation for CDA, CCD, CCR... it's all terrible. http://motorcycleguy.blogspot.com/ seems to be on top of all this stuff and may be able to give you a more definitive answer. Good luck!

Comment: @BrandoBoone Welcome to the club of generating CCD-A, CCD, CCR.  One would think a place like StackOverflow would exist for generating something as critical as person's health record.

Comment: @AlexanderN - For a while [Healthcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it) was fielding some of these questions, but it never gained traction and was subsequently closed. You're right though, this subject certainly needs a better venue for consolidating documentation/specifications and fielding questions (especially where [Meaningful Use](http://www.healthit.gov/policy-researchers-implementers/meaningful-use) is concerned).

Comment: @BrandonBoone I was thinking about starting an open source CCDA generator in C#, just going over that documentation for MU2 is unnecessarily confusing ...